# for-loop doesn't executing

Tags: for-loop, clojure

I'm writing small function and have a strange bug. My for-loop doesn't execute:

```
(fn [resp]
  (let [i
    (s/split resp #"<br>")]
    (for [j i]
      (println j))))
```

So I have no result and doesn't matter what code in my for-section. What's a problem?

---

Edited:
I rewrited my func:

```
(fn [resp]
  (for [i (s/split resp #"<br>")]
    (println i))
```

And it still doesn't executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered the lazy aspect of Clojure's `for` loop:

```
(defn dummy []
  (println :aaa)
  (for [i [1 2 3]]
    (println i))
  (println :bbb)
  (vec
    (for [i [1 2 3]]
      (println i)))
  (println :ccc))
```

when called, you get output:

```
:aaa
:bbb
1
2
3
:ccc
```

The `vec` (or `doall`) will force the lazy loop to be evaluated, thereby causing the `(println i)` expression to run.

You can see more details in [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Comment: OP most likely does not understand the difference between the Clojure `for` macro and a `for` loop in other languages such as C or Java. My best guess is that what OP really wants is something along the lines of `(doseq [i [1 2 3]] (println i))`.